# Maven 3 Parallel Gmaven Sporadic failure

Tags: maven-3, parallel-builds, gmaven

My Maven 3.0.4 parallel build fails intermittently on the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on project opcenter: No providers found matching selection: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on project opcenter: No providers found matching selection: 1.7
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:167)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:163)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: No providers found matching selection: 1.7
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:85)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.gmaven.feature.ProviderException: No providers found matching selection: 1.7
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime.loader.DefaultProviderManager.select(DefaultProviderManager.java:109)
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ProviderMojoSupport.provider(ProviderMojoSupport.java:120)
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.feature(ComponentMojoSupport.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.feature(ComponentMojoSupport.java:42)
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:53)
>       at org.codehaus.gmaven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:69)
>       ... 15 more

My parent pom.xml defines the gmaven plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>1.2</version>
                      <configuration> 
                        <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection> 
                      </configuration> 
                      <dependencies>
                          <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2</version>
                            <exclusions>
                              <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                              </exclusion>
                            </exclusions>




                      </dependency>
                          <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            <version>1.7.0</version>
                          </dependency>
                      </dependencies>
                      <executions>
                          <execution>
                              <goals>
                                      <goal>compile</goal>
                                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
                              </goals>
                          </execution>
                      </executions>
                  </plugin>
```

**Please note** that when I ran the 'mvn groovy:providers' command I see the runtime installed and when I build with a single thread the build succeeds

Answer (score 2):

Currently gmaven does not support parallel builds.

Let's vote for this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMAVEN-87
This change should fix the issue.